# poker hand history analyzer

Tags: desktop, poker

I want to build a poker hand history analyzer that will work on both windows and osx for the desktop.

The user needs to be able to select a set of text files that are parsed into a database on their local machine.

Then the data in the database is displayed with various filter options, info tables and graphs.

What are my options for programming language, database and cross-platform ui?

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a language that you want to work with. This should run on the targets you wish to support. I would pick a language that you find enjoyable to use and enables you to be productive.
2. Pick a database with (nice) bindings for said language that supports said targets. You may want to consider in-process (e.g. lightweight) options to minimize additional system requirements or installation/setup. Analyzing the problem more will reveal what "type" of database, if any, if appropriate.
3. Pick a UI with (nice) bindings for said language that supports said targets. You may have to sacrifice some "portability" with "works like a native app". However, there are plenty of cross-system UI libraries which have countless bindings.

Happy coding.

Comment: i want to use postgres and python. what are my cross platform ui framework options? i'm clueless on the ui because im a web and mobile programmer.

Comment: @Ryan Google likely has some suggestions. Happy searching.

Comment: @Ryan Start with PyQt or WxPython

Answer (score 0):

Build an adobe air app.

Comment: ya i was considering this option.

Answer (score 0):

Why not join forces with [FreepokerDB](http://fpdb.sourceforge.net)?

It's an open-source results tracker and HUD written in python.